# string pop_back function error

Tags: c++, string, vector, struct, stdstring

I am having a problem with modifying a string.  I appreciate your assistance; thank you!

```
struct Drawings::menues
{
    std::vector<std::string> variable;
} Menue[numMenues];


Menue[1].variable.at(0).pop_back();
```

the above code gives me the following error

```
error: 'class std::basic_string<char>' has no member named 'pop_back'|
```

I am using codeblocks 12.11 and am using the gnu gcc compiler and the C++11 flag under compiler settings fixed my problem.

thank you all!

Comment: Does your compiler supports C++11 ? `pop_back` was added in C++11 only.

Comment: [`std::string::pop_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/pop_back) is a new C++11 feature. If your compiler version is to old, or you don't have flags set to enable C++11 mode, then it will not work. Please tell us what compiler and version you use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`pop_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/pop_back) was introduced in C++11. Make sure your compiler supports it and compile with `-std=c++11` (or `-std=c++0x` only if `-std=c++11` is not supported on your version of the compiler).

Comment: +1: Beat me to it. The error message looks like gcc, so probably just a matter of passing the `-std=c++11` flag. Also, note that `-std=c++0x` has been deprecated.

Comment: @JesseGood, Yeah, it's in brackets because `-std=c++11` is better, but that only works on, I think, 4.7 and up.